# React Country Region Select

Tags: reactjs

I have some code about react-country-region-selector, which is suppose to allow me to select the countries and regions, but countries do not get selected and regions remains a dash. Can someone tell me what went wrong with my code?
P.s I am using this site for my code, https://github.com/country-regions/react-country-region-selector

```
import { CountryDropdown, RegionDropdown } from 'react-country-region-selector';
import React, { useState } from "react";
const Locations = () => {
    
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    country: "",
    region: ""
  })

  const selectCountry = (val) => {
    setState({ state: val });
  }

  const selectRegion = (val) =>{
   setState({ state: val });
  }
  const { country, region } = setState;

  return(
         <div>
 <CountryDropdown
          value={country}
          onChange={(val) => selectCountry(val)} />
        <RegionDropdown
          country={country}
          value={region}
          onChange={(val) => selectRegion(val)} />
         </div>
</div>


);
}
return default Locations;
```

What I currently have:

[image]

What I Need:
[image]

Comment: You are not updating the state properly and also not destructuring the state correctly. Here's a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-liskov-0pwu3?file=/src/Locations.js)

Comment: @Yousaf Yep, I just realise after comparing, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do some minor changes.

```
    const selectCountry = (val) => {
    setState({ country: val });

  }

  const selectRegion = (val) =>{
   setState({ region: val });
  }
  const { country, region } = state;

  return(
         <div>
 <CountryDropdown
          value={country}
          onChange={(val) => selectCountry(val)} />
        <RegionDropdown
          country={country}
          value={region}
          onChange={(val) => selectRegion(val)} />
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so its the setState i did, o thanks for that.

Comment: Yes also you should pass the varialbe to const {country, region} like this. Previously you used setState which is used to assgin value to state and doesn't return any value

Comment: `setState({ country: val });` - this will overwrite the existing state - it should be `setState({ ...state, country: val });`. Same goes for the `setState({ region: val });` ----> `setState({ ...state, region: val });`.